# How to create forwarding filter in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

When I create a filter to forward all emails coming from the certain sender -  the "Forward it" box is not active, WHY? need help, please!

Answer (score 1):

When you attempt to create a "forward" filter in Gmail, you need first to create destination emails in settings:

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

[image]